# Using the GAE MapReduce API for Java, how do you collect output from the mapper?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

The map stage is relatively well documented but I can't find any information/tutorials on the reduce stage.

There doesn't seem to be an AppEngineReducer class to go along with the AppEngineMapper.

Is the reduction phase even actually implemented in the current version?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not yet implemented in the Java version - only in Python.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation on developers.google.com:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/dataprocessing/mapreduce_classes#the_reducer_class